# Exchange 2010 to/from 2016 mail flow

Tags: exchange

i just introduced an exchange 2016 server to our existing 2010 environment, the installation and configuration went well, but now i'm having a problem on sending and receiving an email from/to 2010 and 2016, i can send an email to external from both 2010 and 2016 but i cant send between both internal servers, below is the configuration of the receive connectors on 2010 and 2016 respectively.

[Exchange 2010 Receive Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayalp.jpg)

[Exchange 2010 Receive Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxwWN.jpg)

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange 2010 has a bug where the default receive connectors which allow incoming mail from 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 must have the IP address of any newer Exchange server explicitly added to the whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

Primary reason for mail flow failure at this stage is a restriction on the scope, which is allowing connections from a set of external IP addresses only. Therefore I would start there.

The emails should be in a queue - the queue viewer can also give you an indication of the reason for the email delivery failure.