# Error sending and receiving emails in Exchange 2010 and 2016 coexistence

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2016, exchange-migration

These are the versions of the exchange servers:

Exchange 2016 CU23 - 15.1 Build (2507.6)

Exchange 2010 SP3  - 14.3.0513 Build(123.4)

The problem is sending and receiving emails in Exchange 2016.
Creating the send and receive connector in Ex2016:

| Send | Receive | message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ex2010 | Internet | OK |
| Internet | Ex2010 | OK |
| Ex2016 | Internet | 4.4.7 Queue Expired |
| Internet | Ex2016 | 4.4.7 Queue Expired |
| Ex2010 | Ex2016 | 4.4.7 Queue Expired |
| Ex2016 | Ex2010 | OK |

Without connector to send and by default receive in Ex2016:

| Send | Receive | message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ex2010 | Internet | OK |
| Internet | Ex2010 | OK |
| Ex2016 | Internet | OK |
| Internet | Ex2016 | 4.4.7 Queue Expired |
| Ex2010 | Ex2016 | 4.4.7 Queue Expired |
| Ex2016 | Ex2010 | OK |

Perform tests with [Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/exchange). The test mail arrives and passes the tests.Also with [Chektls](https://www.checktls.com/TestReceiver) and without problems

Reading on the internet, there are more [problems in Ex2010](https://serverfault.com/questions/847071/exchange-2010-to-from-2016-mail-flow), I was thinking if this problem is corrected by recreating the [connectors as done in Exchange 2003 - 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-2010/aa997292(v=exchg.141)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Reviewing the [RDN message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/email-delivery/ndr/non-delivery-reports-in-exchange-online) in a little detail, I realize that it only checks the message in Ex2010 and does not ask in Ex2016 if the mailbox exists. I have created test mailboxes on both servers and I can access them in OWA, that is where I have these problems sending and receiving emails

Ex2010 in 10 MX Ex2010.contoso.com

Ex2016 in 20 MX Ex2016.contoso.com

Comment: I found that there seems to be a same case in Microsoft QA Forum https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1442152/error-sending-and-receiving-emails-in-exchange-201
And you may could refer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for the help and patience it took me to respond.

I found the problem, it was configuring physical firewall policies. While testing with telnet I realized the problem.

---

- Internal test of Exchange 2016 to 2010 and 2010 to 2016. connect
  without problems the telnet the server responds.
- External exchange test with  since Ex2016 is waiting for a
  connection, with Ex2010 the response connection is fast.

> telnet test.smtp.org 25

This is a free test server for connection.

This is where I see the difference in connection, despite performing several test tests with [Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/exchange) and everything went well without problems.

- I configure the policies and routes in the physical firewall.
  Everything works without problems.